# How do I create a custom scala library using sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Like it says on the tin, how would I go by creating a library using sbt?

I have a set of utilities and convenience functions that I want to be easily distributed between my projects. The easiest way to do this of course, is by having them compile to a library, that I can then include in the build path of any given project that'll use it.

Libraries are often much easier to include in multiple projects than having multiple copies of the same classes. So how would I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just create a project with the library code, and use the `publishLocal` command to put it in your local Ivy repo. Then you can include it in other projects.

This next bit may be overkill for your case, but I have [this blog post](http://www.joescii.com/2014/02/24/oss-scala-starter-kit/) outlining how to do all of this for an open source project.  Perhaps you'll use it as inspiration to make it available for us all to enjoy. :)

Comment: I see it compiles to `.class` files... I thought libraries were `.jar`s unless I'm mistaken

Comment: Yes, `package` will package them into a jar file.  `publish-local` depends on that task, and then places the jar into your local ivy repo at `~/.ivy/local`

Comment: From the `sbt` command prompt, execute the `publish-local` task.  It will put the class files in a jar and make them available to other projects via the local ivy cache.  Then you can include it as a dependency in your other projects.

Comment: but what if I want to make the library available and distributable? So I can use it across multiple computers

Comment: Have you read the blog entry he linked to yet? It explains how to do this.

Comment: Is this something open source, or private to your organization?

Comment: @joescii it's open to everyone

Comment: Then my aforementioned blog post is exactly what you're looking for. :)  It'll walk you through the whole process.  Let me know if you have more questions after you go through it.

Comment: @joescii it just seems like an unnecessarily complicated process... It should be easier than that to just make a few libraries. I mean in C# it's practically part of the compiler, so why isn't it here?

Comment: Well, I know nothing about C#.  For what it's worth, that post describes more than just the publishing aspect, which is what you've asked about.  The publishing has several steps mostly for ensuring the artifacts are uploaded by the author(s) of the library.

Comment: oh I didn't need anything about the publishing.. All I wanted was knowing how to compile jars I can include in any project regardless of computer. So like I can keep them on a USB stick along with `gson` and `apache commons io` and such to easily include in whatever projects I may be working on. BUT I'll keep the source on github, thus keeping it open. That's what I thought you meant by open source

Comment: Oh, now I'm with you.  You'll just need to run the `package` task, and the jar will be located in the `target/scala-2.XX` directory, where `XX` is your scala version.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee I know thinking about Maven and stuff is a bit arcane, but it's worthwhile to invest the time into learning the basics. SBT is built to interface nicely with those tools, and anybody else who may want to use your libraries will really easily be able to link to those projects in the most familiar way -- kind of like NPM, Gem, or Pip.